# Not able to enter a record in mysql db in python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, database

I am not able to enter a record in mysql database.

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    password = "root@123",
    database = "testdb",
    )

print(mydb)

my_cursor = mydb.cursor()
sql_query = ("INSERT INTO users (name,email,age) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")
record1 = ('Tim','Tim123',45)
records = [("Ankit","ankit345",30),
    ("shubhra","shubhra567",29),
    ("anita","anit789",55),]
my_cursor.execute(sql_query,records)
mydb.commit()
```

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    password = "root@123",
    database = "testdb",
    )

print(mydb)

my_cursor = mydb.cursor()
sql_query = ("INSERT INTO users (name,email,age) VALUES (%s %s %s)")
record1 = ('Tim','Tim123',45)
my_cursor.execute(sql_query,record1)
mydb.commit()
```

Administrator@DESKTOP-60U78C6 MINGW64 /c/mysql
$ python db1.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db1.py", line 15, in 
    my_cursor.execute(sql_query,record1)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 569, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 553, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 442, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '45)' at line 1

Comment: Looks like you need commas between the three  %s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing commas between the values:

```
sql_query = ("INSERT INTO users (name,email,age) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")
# Here ----------------------------------------------------^---^
```

Comment: I have added code for multiple records. It is not working. What is the error?